# setProgress: animated: not working (during HTML parsing)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

I parse HTML Data from a Website with the help of the TFHppleElement. Now during the parsing in the for loop I want to update the progressView but it isn't working. Why?

My Code:

**ParseHTMLData.m**

```
for (...) {

        ...
        for (...) {

                for (...) {

                    ...
                }
        }

            SecondViewController *svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
            float prog = 0.9f; //For testing a fix value
            [svc setProgressAnimated:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:prog]];

    }
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
-(void)setProgressAnimated: (NSNumber *)number;
{
    [self.progressView setProgress:[number floatValue] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Are you doing the parsing in a separate thread? Can you confirm that it is hitting the call to setProgressAnimated: and is actually reaching the function.

Comment: What do you mean with seperate thread? How can I do that? Multithreading?

Comment: It could be that Hpple is parsing the HTML in a separate NSOperationQueue (i.e. not on the main thread) to the main queue, which means that you can't do UI updates from it. Therefore you must executing your setProgress: method on the [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]

Comment: @ProgrammingThomas How can I do that?

Comment: [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        SecondViewController *svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
        float prog = 0.9f; //For testing a fix value
        [svc setProgressAnimated:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:prog]];
    }];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got working it by doing it like this. So it is parsing in the background and I can update the UI.

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        for (...) {

        ...
        for (...) {

                for (...) {

                    ...
                }
        }
    }
});
```